# how can i get items in a named array randomly

Tags: javascript

i want to display questions and below i want to put a textbox for answer. for eg. What is the capital of India.. When the page loads at first time this question appears.. when loads second time another question should appear randomly how to write.. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of questions, `var questions = ["asdf", "sdfg", ...];` then you can get random ones by:

```
questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
```

Edit: For associative arrays...

Just create a normal array from it:

```
var questions = [];
for (var i in assocArr) {
   if (assocArr.hasOwnProperty(i)) questions.push(assocArr[i]);
}
```

And then use the above method.

Comment: this is the case of normal arrays.. but how to use this one in named arrays means associative arrays...!

Comment: @Mihir, I don't think they should be in an associative array, but if they must, see my ammended answer.

Comment: Don't forget to add a check for `assocArr.hasOwnProperty(i)` when using a `for ... in` loop.